# Find the missing number in the given puzzle

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

[image]

<sup>Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsgr8.jpg)</sup>

Source: My coaching DPP (Daily Practice Paper)

A) $112$

B) $92$

C) $82$

D) $102$

I found $5^2+3^2-4^2=18,\,7^2+5^2-3^2=65.$ So, $?=8^2+6^2-5^2=75$ which is not in option. Anyone please help.

Comment: This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, proper attribution is required. Can you please include the source for this puzzle?

Comment: What is a "DPP"?

Comment: it is 102 or 112 (intuition)

Comment: Daily Practice Paper=DPP

Comment: My guess, it should be multiple of 6 i.e. 102

Comment: or a multiple of 8 -> 112 that was why I chose these two ;)

Comment: look at this! somebody starts to write 112 and there is a square root sign LOL.  Now what?  https://brainly.in/question/12990472  No the number changed, is 8 or 9? because your solution would fit perfectly

Answer (score 4):

Since our dear friend [balazs.com](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/90991/63153) has not deigned to provide a comprehensible explanation to us lowly mortals, I've provided a simple explanation here:

The missing number is:

> **Not the only one missing**

This is because:

> You have correctly deduced the pattern for turning the outside numbers into the inside number. Specifically, the pattern adds the squares of the upper outside numbers and subtracts the square of the lower outside number to produce the inner number. As shown here:
>
> ```
>  5*5 + 3*3 - 4*4 = 25 + 9 - 16 = 18
>  7*7 + 5*5 - 3*3 = 49 + 25 - 9 = 65
> ```
>
> The problem is that the third triangle is malformed per the available answer choices.
>  The actual equation you're looking for is: `9*9 + 6*6 - 5*5 = 81 + 36 - 25 = 92`.
>  Therefore, the answer (central missing number) is **B) 92**, and the other missing number is **9**, which should replace the misprinted 8 on the top left of the third triangle.

Comment: I upvoted:)  Much better! Sorry for laziness..

Comment: @balazs.com No problem, just try to write more in future :)

Comment: I don't think assuming the puzzle itself is wrong is the right way. Otherwise every puzzle will be "wrongified" to suit our existing solution that coincidentally matches some examples.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir This is a [pre-existing question](https://brainly.in/question/12990472) with evidence of something changed in-between, not an original question. However, you are correct - it's normally not good to assume "wrongification".

Comment: Sure, but there is a very blurry number in a very sensitive place. I found it a weird coincidence, but you still can be 49% right (very blurry - in the other picture, you have not seen that picture yet!)

Answer (score 2):

> it is 92 and there is a mistake on the picture;)

Comment: You see, I told you, your solution is correct, we had to find the right question to it!  And you did not believe me, rejected my edit:)

Comment: The mistake being that an 8 has been printed instead of a 9...

Comment: I think you are right.Sorry for rejection as I thought it would spoil the question.

Comment: No, I am just joking. Since I didn`t edit 8 to 9 but  instead included E)75 as an option. (It was only a joke,sorry. But "there's a grain of truth in every joke")

Comment: @balazs.com You earned a truly **Explainer** badge here :P (Edit the question and answer it... if you could edit the image :D)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is number

> 102, because the right number of the triangle divides the number inside the triangle and the other numbers don't have this property. As 6 divides 102 but not 82, 92,112 ->  D) looks like the correct answer to me.